# List of values from sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database with a few tables organized like this : `date|type|zone|value`. There are a lot of entries, but only a few zones. How can I have a list of all the zones, with only one time each zone ?

Comment: Do you need the unique list of zones across all tables?

Comment: Nop, I need a list for each of the tables.

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT zone FROM tablename"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DISTINCT` query per table:

```
for tablename in list_of_tablenames:
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT zone FROM {}'.format(tablename))
    zones = [r[0] for r in cursor]
```